# robust estimator when $\mu/\sigma$ is constant

Tags: robust, estimators

I have a large set of measurements consisting each of about 100 points, (normally distributed), with up to 20% outliers. The outliers are all shifted towards positive values.
From the physics, I know that
$\dfrac{\sigma}{\mu}$ = constant
Furthermore, I know this ratio to within 5%

I currently use either a Ransac(-like) algorithm and/or the Hodges-Lehmann estimator to obtain the 'mean' value. I am wondering, given that I approximately know the ratio between $\mu$ and $\sigma$ does a better estimator exist?

Finally, let me apologize, I am not a statician nor a mathematician. Therefore my question might seem trivial. I might also not use the proper terms. However I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What's physics of the phenomenon?

Comment: I measure the noise power output of a low noise amplifier.  Essentially it is the autocorrelation of a random signal, where the std/mean is inversely proportional to the square root of the Bandwidth-time product.

Comment: Why do you call 20% of observations outliers? Is it based on statistics or physics? 20% is quite a lot for tests like Gruber's to handle. It works relatively well for one point in a sample.

Comment: the measurement is very sensitive to RFI (radio frequency interference). We performed measurements outside of the EMC chamber and given the shielding factor, about 20% should be disturbed. From visual inspection, I can easily reject 15% (more then 10x to 1000x stronger than my signal). However the final 5% is within the distribution. When correlating with the RFI, I can see a slight offset in the 'mean' when RFI is present.

Comment: I'm having a cognitive dissonance here reconciling the notion of a low noise filter which is at the same time very sensitive to RFI. It seems that you may build your own robust estimator based on the physics of the phenomenon. You clearly have at least two sources of noise. One being the thermal and the other from RFI. Your $\sigma$ refers to thermal noise, but there's another $\sigma_{RFI}$, which is much stronger. You should incorporate it into your estimator somehow, me thinks